# Flat shading when using displacement or bump

Tags: node-editor, shaders

[image: Flat shading on icosphere (subdivision level 5]

When using a bump or displacement node and bump only or displacement and bump in the material settings, the shade smooth option seems to not be working. Instead the geometry starts to show, auto smooth does not help either. Adding more geometry fixes the issue but defeats the purpose of using a bump map in the first place. This issue makes it unusable in many scenarios. Any ideas on how to fix this are highly appreciated!

Edit: .blend file added.
[image]

Comment: Please provide the blend file so we can take a closer look. Use [Blend Exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/)

Comment: I also tried using Bump node plugged directly into the Normal of BSDF intstead of using Displacement Map, but still same problem. it looks like a known limitation, there are several other threads complaining about displacement map not working with smooth shading with no answers. one workaround is to apply a 3-level subdivision modifier with a UV sphere.